# Error: Could not find or load main class version

Tags: java, macos

I have downloaded Java on mac mavericks system. But when I type on terminal to see the Java version using  command:

```
java version
```

I get the following error

> Could not find or load main class version

I went to oracle website and tried a check to see if Java is installed on my system,which confirmed the Java7 is installed on the system. But why can I not see version in terminal?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try

```
 java -version
```

Without the minus sign it is trying to load a program called version.

Answer (score 2):

java -version is the command  to check java version

Download latest Java SE from Oracle site and install it. Then reopen cmd and check java version using java -version.

Set the Java path to bin and check it's version also. Both java and javac should be on same version.

In my case:

C:\Users\darshan>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Users\darshan>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_121